# Singular value decomposition with positive values?

Tags: linear-algebra

We know that thin SVD for a matrix $A$ minimizes the squared error between $U \Sigma V'$ and $A$ where $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix of some of the singular values and $U$ and $V$ are unitary matrices.

Is there anything like SVD (a mathematical formulation and an algorithm) that decomposes $A$ into $U$ and $V$ such that all values in the cells of $U$ and $V$ are positive?

(In general, $U$ and $V$, of course don't have to be positive.)

EDIT:
I am looking for a way to project a high dimensional data into lower dimensional space such that the lower dimension values are all positive.

EDIT 2: I would be also happy with U and V not all being positive, but with U and V that project the columns and rows of A into all positive values, i.e. SVD with a restriction that the projections project to positive values.

Comment: If such a thing existed, it would be very different from the SVD, because matrices with all positive entries are very non-unitary.

Comment: I meant, similar to SVD in the sense that it can be used to approximate the original matrix. (edited to clarify, thanks.)

Comment: Why not just write an optimization problem for it? Something like the Matrix Completion problem?

Comment: thanks Inquest -- can you be more clear how it be formulated as a matrix completion problem? I don't see that.